# PC Reboot When Stressed

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, crash, gpu, reboot

My father bought a new rig last week.

It's a HP Envy Phoenix with:

- GEFORCE GTX 780 3072MB (*Think it had GTX 760 stock*)
- Intel i7 4770 3.4 GHz
- 16GB of RAM
- ...

**When under heavy load the computer restarts itself**.
I've tested it with Battlefield 3, Tera Online and **FurMark** 1.13.0. I've ran FurMark on a low resolution and it **instantly** restarted.

The **GPU** uses **latest** available **drivers**.

The **PSU** is a stock one from **HP**. Model: **DPS-600WB A**

**GPU says it requires a 600W power supply minimum.** Could it be that the **PSU** is too weak or are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Are you looking at your temperatures when doing these tests? Is the computer set to autorestart? I tend to agree with Ahsesh on a hp stock, but I run a 7950 8 hard drives, overclocked same cpu and 32gig of ram on a 620W psu selected specific for that job (it is capable beyond that).  http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-780-ti-review-benchmarks,3663-17.html  shows a max of ~200w But still a cruddy stock manufactures drop in psu , probably. But there are always other possibilites.  If you have a simple driver crash, it still wouldnt hurt to have a good PSU :-)

Comment: The temperatures while doing nothing are around 30 degrees C on both **GPU** and **CPU**. While doing **FurMark** I can't check the temperature because the computer really restarts right away. While playing Tera Online on MAX settings for example, I had temperatures around 40-60 degrees C. It works until I do some combo or something. Looks like it restarts when the GPU requires more power.

Comment: Ok, it does sound like power is the problem.  Is the bios set to power up or remain off on a wall socket blackout?  I would want to know more.  Windows OS can do a restart just because it crashed, and really a bios should not be set to power up on a wall socket fail (unless it is a server) because of nasty browns and surges that can occur during brownouts and blackouts.  I always set mine to remain off. sooo I would want to know why it restarts instead of giving up on you :-)

Comment: BIOS is set to remain off @ electricity blackout.

Comment: The graphics card driver version is **337.88**.
The **GTX 760** that I guess was stock mounted has minimum recommended system power of **500W**.

Comment: If you have not, you could turn that auto restart off . Go to the Control Pannel, System, Advanced system settings, Advanced tab, in the System Failure section, make sure "[X] Write an event to the system log" is checked and uncheck "[ ] Automatic Restart".  . Then the Power to the gpu, do you have at least 2X6pin connections on the GPU? To clean the metal (oxidations) on the connections there a person can slide those off then back on again, that will "improve" the connection and check it at the same time (as you look at it).

Comment: It would make sence to have replaced the original PSU when replacing the GPU. It makes sence to replace them just because manufactured computers I have seen have some really bad PSUs tossed in them :-)  So that was just other possibilities, all your info provided still points to the PSU as you suspected.

Comment: @Snewix Adding support to everybody else here; you need a power supply that meets your minimum system requirements before you can even attempt to diagnose this problem effectively (and it is likely the cause anyways). That power supply is spec'd at 600W *peak* (not even continuous) and your GPU max usage is only 100W below that, and that's not counting the other hardware in your system. Calculate the required power for all your hardware, add 20% for good measure, then find a PSU with that rating for *continuous* output. Then come back here if you still have issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need more power to run heavy games.

Calculate how much power does the system requires and replace your PSU with the appropriate PSU.

[Calculate PSU Requirements](http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp)

Comment: +1. The HP power supply spec is 600W; and that's 600W *peak*. Your (@Snewix) GPU requires 500W *minimum* and that doesn't even include all the rest of the hardware in your system. Before you event attempt to diagnose this problem, get a power supply that meets your system requirements (and it is most probably the cause of the issue).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace your PSU and you should be good to go.

I saw the product specifications and power requirements, there's a **diffrence of 100W** between them. Obvioisly it's the PSU because **branded PCs come with just the bare minimum PSU needed. So as to cut on cost, specially HP**
You can check on hp's website to see that your PSU is under-rated.

It can not be a driver issue becquse you are running the latest version available.

Comment: Why do you think that PSU is the culprit?